# Xstream parsing multiple list

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xstream

I have a xml file where there are multiple arrays in the root element. Whenever am trying to use the implicitcollection declaration, the xstream is only processing the last declaration and everything else remains null. In the below code the first array ERRORS remains null whereas DEBITS is parsed.

```
public class XMLParser {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String xmlString = "<DebitsWSDS xmlns=\"\"> " + 
                                 "  <DEBITS> " + 
                                 "    <DEBIT_ID>-1</DEBIT_ID> " + 
                                 "  </DEBITS> " + 
                                 "  <DEBITS> " + 
                                 "    <DEBIT_ID>-2</DEBIT_ID> " + 
                                 "  </DEBITS> " + 
                                 "  <ERRORS> " + 
                                 "    <ERROR_ID>1</ERROR_ID> " + 
                                 "  </ERRORS> " + 
                                 "  <ERRORS> " + 
                                 "    <ERROR_ID>2</ERROR_ID> " + 
                                 "  </ERRORS> " + 
                            "</DebitsWSDS> ";
        DebitsWSDS debitsWSDS;
        try {
            debitsWSDS = convertFeesSetXMLResultToDebitsWSDS(xmlString);
            System.out.println(debitsWSDS.ERRORS==null);
            System.out.println(debitsWSDS.DEBITS==null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


private static DebitsWSDS convertFeesSetXMLResultToDebitsWSDS(String xml) throws Exception{

        XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
            xstream.alias("DebitsWSDS", DebitsWSDS.class);
        xstream.addImplicitCollection(DebitsWSDS.class, "DEBITS");
        xstream.addImplicitCollection(DebitsWSDS.class, "ERRORS");
        xstream.alias("ERROR_ID", String.class);
        //System.out.println(xml);
        DebitsWSDS debitsWSDS =(DebitsWSDS)xstream.fromXML(xml);
        return debitsWSDS;
    }

}




public class DebitsWSDS {

        public List<ERROR> ERRORS;
        public List<DEBIT> DEBITS;

    public class ERROR {
        public String ERROR_ID;
    }

    public class DEBIT {
        public String DEBIT_ID;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you'd expect it to do. XStream is a bean/XML mapping tool, and you effectively have two XML lists mapped to the same `List` element in your bean. If you really want that XML strucutre I would construct your bean using a SAX parser or similar, create an empty list and let the parser callbacks add to that list.